# VSCode devcontainers: git permission denied when cloning a second repository inside the same devcontainer

Tags: git, vscode-devcontainer

Cloning a repository (let's call it "main repository") in dev container work fine.

Cloning another repository inside the same dev container does not work (permission denied).

### Steps to reproduce:

- In VSCode, "Clone repository in container volume" (from the menu). From there, everything work fine:

  - From the gui (pull, push)
  - From integrated terminal: "git pull", "git push" work fine
- Opening a "integrated terminal" (running from inside the dev container), and try to clone another repository inside:

  - git clone git@github.com:... => permission denied

This is strange:

=> Why does the "main" repository work fine (with authorization), while another repository (where the credentials are the same) does not ?

### Informations:

- The devcontainer is a ubuntu:latest
- Credentials are valid
- I can "Clone repository in container volume" the secondary repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, VSCode containers use "https" to checkout from git.

The solution is to use https://github.com/... to checkout the secondary repository.